# Is there a way to associate for each plot the relative legend using plotly?

Tags: python, plotly, subplot

I'm using `plotly.subplots` to generate a subplot of 2 `plotly.express` elements. The result is printed below. I would like to obtain 2 different legends, with the associated element for each plot.
[image]

Here is the code used for generated the plots:

```
fig1 =px.line(df, x=df.index, y='average')
fig1.add_scatter(x=df.index, y=df['ave_10'],mode='lines', name='MA 10',opacity=0.6)
fig1.add_scatter(x=df.index, y=df['ave_50'],mode='lines', name='MA 50',opacity=0.6)


# plot volume
fig2= px.line(df, x=df.index, y='Volume')


# combine the 2 graphs
fig = make_subplots(rows=2,cols=1,subplot_titles = ['Average values of {} with moving average at 10 and 50 lags'.format(code),'Volume'])

for data in fig1.data:
    fig.add_trace((go.Scatter(x=data['x'],y=data['y'], name = data['name'])),row=1,col=1)

for data in fig2.data:
    fig.add_trace((go.Scatter(x=data['x'],y=data['y'], name = data['name'])),row=2,col=1)


fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Plotly supports only one legend per graph. They recommend you use annotations instead. You can do better with matplotlib.

Comment: What are you referring to when you say using annotations instead? I can not use matplotlib for this task

Comment: https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/.  Scroll to the bottom.